# Any suggestions for letting user Activation by clicking link OR typing in confirmation code?

Tags: login, registration, password, confirmation

Sometimes,  our users do not have access to their email on the same device they are using our web app on, for example, they can check their email on their iphone, but the iphone is too small to use the webapp on.

And I want to maintain the flow:

1. Signup
2. Login (without confirmation allowed for 1 day)
3. confirm email
4. set password save password on  that device
5. start using it

So, if they are *already* in the app when they realize they need to activate, i'd rather (if they can't check email on that device) go to their phone, get the code, and type it there so that they can set

So I'm considering letting them use either a 4 digit code or click the hyperlink.
Of course, choice causes friction :(  so I want to carefully consider this.
This complicates both the email and the dialog for activating the account.

THE PLAN

1. The activation email would have the 4 digit code AFTER the Activation Button
   **Activate Your Account**
           or, if the webapp is currently prompting you you can enter your 
   Activation Code:   1234
2. If they log in and haven't activated their email then they's see:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you check activation status with a background process.

Comment: Make some ajax request with interval timer to check if account is activated somewhere (any device). Remove "I Activated My Free Trial" button and "Code Input" from interface. And if account is activated forward user to account page directly...